# Ajax post request does not update with render in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I have a form that post 2 fields to the server with the `"remote => true"` and I have `format.js` in my controller.

If I in my create.js.erb use object values it works fine but if I want to render a included file the js fails to do so.

I have a div with an id called container that will be updated with the data.

The create.js.erb file looks like this:

```
$('#container').html(<%= escape_javascript(render('index')) %>);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
 def create
    @casepost = Casepost.new(params[:casepost])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @casepost.save

        @caseposts = Casepost.all

        format.html
        format.js# { render json: @casepost, status: :created, location: @casepost }
      else

        @caseposts = Casepost.all

        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js# { render json: @casepost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

THe file I want to render puts out the content of an array called @caseposts.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @caseposts.each do |casepost| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= casepost.title %></td>
    <td><%= casepost.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', casepost %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_casepost_path(casepost) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', casepost, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />


<%= link_to 'New Casepost', new_casepost_path %>
```

Comment: After testing some I found out that I can't have newlines or link_to's in my code. Is Ajax crippled somehow?